# Error: missing type specifier

Tags: c++, c++11, visual-studio-2013

I'm trying to do my first application on C++ using MVC pattern. So, I have a view class, ClientTsFrm, and the ClientTS class, the controller. To notify to the view class, I decided to use the Observer pattern, so ClienTS heritages from Subject.h.

ClientTsFrm has a member called ClientTS in order to do a communication, but when I build the project, it shows this error:

> Error 10  error C4430: missing type specifier - int assumed. Note: C++ does not support default-int (src\lib\ClientTS.cpp)
>
> Error 9   error C2146: syntax error : missing ';' before identifier 'clientts' (src\lib\ClientTS.cpp)

ClientTsFrm.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
    #pragma hdrstop
#endif

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
    #include <wx/wx.h>
    #include <wx/frame.h>
#else
    #include <wx/wxprec.h>
#endif

#include "../Data/config.h"
#include "../lib/ClientTS.h"
#include "../data/Session.h"
#include "../data/Message.h" 

#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/timer.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/richtext/richtextctrl.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>
#include "NationList.h"
#include "LoginWarnings.h" 
#include "../ArchiveLog.h"

#include "../GlobalVariables.h"
#include "../translateController/translateController.h"
#include "../translateController/translateVariable.h"
#include "FrmMailSending.h"
#include "FrmSettingMail.h"
#include "AudioWizard.h"
#include <list>
#include "FrmSaveChat.h"
//#include "../data/observer.h"

#define MENU_ESCI 1800
#define MENU_OPZIONI 1801
#define MENU_SPEECH 1802

class ClientTsFrm : public wxFrame
{
    private:
        DECLARE_EVENT_TABLE();
        double conta;
        void askForSaving();
        void WxButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void btnsendClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void txtchatClick(wxRichTextEvent& event);
        void txtchatEnter(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnTimerTimeout(wxTimerEvent& event);
        void WxTimer1Timer(wxTimerEvent& event);
        void txtmsgEnter(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void RefreshChat();
        void btnspeechClick(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void ClientTsFrmActivate(wxActivateEvent& event);
        void WxButton2Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void WxTimer2Timer(wxTimerEvent& event);
        void gridchatCellLeftClick(wxGridEvent& event);
        void Debug(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void Wizard(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void WxBitmapButton1Click(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void Mail(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void SettingMail(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void Save(wxCommandEvent& event);
        void OnClose(wxCloseEvent& event);

        void notifyMsg(MessagePTR msg);

    public:

        ClientTsFrm(LoginWarnings *warn, wxWindow *parent, wxWindowID id = 1, const wxString &title = wxT("TeamTranslate"),
                    const wxPoint& pos = wxDefaultPosition, const wxSize& size = wxDefaultSize, 
                    long style = wxCAPTION | wxSYSTEM_MENU | wxCLOSE_BOX | wxRESIZE_BORDER);

        virtual ~ClientTsFrm();

        //void ClientTsFrm::notify(ClientTsFrm fn);

    private:
        Session* session;
        ConfigPTR config;
        NationList *nations;
        int REFRESHTIMER = 0;
        uint64 _sclogID;
        wxTimer *WxTimer2;
        wxTimer *WxTimer1;
        wxButton *btnspeech;
        wxRichTextCtrl *txtclient;
        wxTextCtrl *txtlingua;
        wxStaticText *lbllingua;
        wxStaticText *lblnick;
        wxTextCtrl *txtnick;
        wxRichTextCtrl *txtchat;
        wxButton *btnsend;
        wxTextCtrl *txtmsg;
        wxGrid *gridchat;
        wxGrid *gridclient;
        wxBoxSizer *sizer;
        wxGridSizer *gridsizer;
        wxMenuBar *WxMenuBar1;
        wxMenu *ID_MNU_FILE_1001_Mnu_Obj;
        wxMenu *ID_MNU_OPZIONI_1004_Mnu_Obj;
        wxBitmapButton *WxBitmapButton1;
        ClientTS clientts;
};
```

ClientTS.h

```
#pragma once

#ifdef __BORLANDC__
#pragma hdrstop
#endif

#ifndef WX_PRECOMP
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/frame.h>
#else
#include <wx/wxprec.h>
#endif

#include "../gui/ClientTsFrm.h"
#include "../data/Session.h"
#include "../data/Message.h"
#include "../data/Config.h" 

#include <wx/sizer.h>
#include <wx/wx.h>
#include <wx/timer.h>
#include <wx/stattext.h>
#include <wx/richtext/richtextctrl.h>
#include <wx/textctrl.h>
#include <wx/button.h>
#include <wx/grid.h>
#include "../gui\NationList.h"
#include "../gui\NationInfo.h" 
#include "../ArchiveLog.h"

#include "../GlobalVariables.h"
#include "../translateController/translateController.h"
#include "../translateController/translateVariable.h"

#include <list>
#include <functional>
#include "Subject.h"

#include "EventType.h"


#define MENU_ESCI 1800
#define MENU_OPZIONI 1801
#define MENU_SPEECH 1802

class ClientTS : public Subject<EventTS>{
    static Session* session;
    static  ConfigPTR config;
    static bool flagSave;
    static char LANG_MSG_SRC[500];
    static char MSG_SRC[500];

public:
    ClientTS(){
        session = Session::Instance();
        config = session->getConfig();
    }
    ~ClientTS(){}

    static char* getLANG_MSG_SRC(){ return LANG_MSG_SRC; }

    static char* getMSG_SRC(){ return MSG_SRC; }

    static bool getFlagSave(){ return flagSave; }

    static void setFlagSave(bool flg){ flagSave = flg; }

    static void speak(char *LANG, char*MSG);
    static void Print(char*word);
    static size_t read_callback(static void *ptr, size_t size, size_t nmemb, static void *userp);
    static void writeWaveFile(const char* filename, SAudioStreamFormat format, static void* data);
    static void SetupColor();
    static void onConnectStatusChangeEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, int newStatus, unsigned int errorNumber);
    static void onNewChannelEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, uint64 channelParentID);
    static void onNewChannelCreatedEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, uint64 channelParentID, anyID invokerID, const char* invokerName, const char* invokerUniqueIdentifier);
    static void onDelChannelEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID, anyID invokerID, const char* invokerName, const char* invokerUniqueIdentifier);
    static void onClientMoveEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID, uint64 oldChannelID, uint64 newChannelID, int visibility, const char* moveMessage);
    static void onClientMoveSubscriptionEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID, uint64 oldChannelID, uint64 newChannelID, int visibility);
    static void onClientMoveTimeoutEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID, uint64 oldChannelID, uint64 newChannelID, int visibility, const char* timeoutMessage);
    static void onTalkStatusChangeEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, int status, int isReceivedWhisper, anyID clientID);
    static void onIgnoredWhisperEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID clientID);
    static void onServerErrorEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, const char* errorMessage, unsigned int error, const char* returnCode, const char* extraMessage);
    static void onUserLoggingMessageEvent(const char* logMessage, int logLevel, const char* logChannel, uint64 logID, const char* logTime, const char* completeLogString);
    static void onCustomPacketEncryptEvent(char** dataToSend, unsigned int* sizeOfData);
    static void onCustomPacketDecryptEvent(char** dataReceived, unsigned int* dataReceivedSize);
    static void onEditMixedPlaybackVoiceDataEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, short* samples, int sampleCount, int channels, const unsigned int* channelSpeakerArray, unsigned int* channelFillMask);
    static void showChannels(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void showChannelClients(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, uint64 channelID);
    static void onTextMessageEvent(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, anyID targetMode, anyID toID, anyID fromID, const char* fromName, const char* fromUniqueIdentifier, const char* message);
    static void showClients(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void createChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID, const char *name);
    static void deleteChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void renameChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void switchChannel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void toggleVAD(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void setVadLevel(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void requestWhisperList(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void requestClearWhisperList(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static void toggleRecordSound(uint64 serverConnectionHandlerID);
    static int readIdentity(char* identity);
    static int writeIdentity(const char* identity);
    static uint64  enterChannelID();
    static void createDefaultChannelName(char *name);
    static void enterName(char *name);
};
```

Hope someone could help me. If you need more code, just let me know please.

Thank you for your time.

Edit. The error is on this line (ClientTsFrm.h):

```
  ClientTS clientts;
```

Comment: On what lines do you get the errors?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg on this line  ``ClientTS clientts;``

Comment: What's going on here: Error 50 error C2143: syntax error : missing ';' before '*' (src\lib\ClientTS.cpp)?

Comment: where ClientTS is declared?

Comment: Please show some more context, what happens before that line? And the error message mentions a *source* file (`ClientTS.cpp`), what's happening in that file?

Comment: Yes, where I declare the clientts variable.

clientts.cpp is about 2000 lines.  You can check the whole project here: https://github.com/danieltoledo/speech-translation-tools/tree/teamspeak/client/src/lib

Comment: Just show the offending lines in `ClientTS.cpp` and some context (i.e. a few lines before).

Comment: Have you included ClientTS.h in your ClientTsFrm.h...?

Comment: @JoachimPileborg Thank you for your interest. I added some lines of ClientTsFrm ClientTS but about the other file, ClientTS.cpp, is just the implementation of all the functions but the constructor. 
.

Yes, I included ClientTS.h

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The two headers each try to include the other, which is impossible. One will be included first, and won't have access to the declarations in the other.

As far as I can see, `ClientTS.h` doesn't need anything from `ClientTsFrm.h`, so just remove that inclusion.